# Install futures for python2

Tags: python, pip, python-2.x, concurrent.futures

I have various versions of `Python` on my `Ubuntu` OS.
When I want to install futures, it writes the following message:

`$ sudo pip2 install futures`

`Requirement already satisfied: futures in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (3.1.1)`

When uninstall it and install it again, it does not help.

How would you install `futures` for `Python2`?

All the pips that I have (pip, pip2, pip2.7, pip3, pip3.6, pip3.7, pip3.8) point here:
`pip 20.2.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)`

Can I change it?

Comment: Since python2 is not suported anymore i'm not surprised that pip does not work. Probably install/compile it manually

Comment: If you would type `python` to run Python 2, use `python -m pip install futures` to run pip for python 2.

Comment: @zvone This solved it `python2.7 -m pip install futures`. You can write it as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `pip install something` may do what you expect if everything is configured well, but in general it often happens that you do not really know in which python that is going to install something.

To be certain in which python you are installing, it is best to run `python -m pip` instead of just `pip`. That way you can choose exactly which python installation should be updated, by simply using the same Python you would use to run later when you use the installed library e.g.:

```
python -m pip install something
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install something
```

or

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 -m pip install something
```

or

```
"C:\Program Files\Python3.6\python.exe" -m pip install something
```

or ...